# Looking for a better way to reduce array and determine if numbers are in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

```js
const dice = [1,3,4,5,6]
const score = straightScore(dice,4)

    function straightScore(dice, sizeOfStraight) {
        let score = 0
        sizeOfStraight > 4 ? score = 40 : score = 30
        dice.sort( (a, b) => a-b )
        // filter to eliminate duplicates
        const filteredDice = dice.reduce( (acc, die) => {
            if ( acc.indexOf(die) === -1 ) acc.push(die)
            return acc
        }, [] )
        //determine straight
        const straightFinder = filteredDice.reduce( (acc, die) => {
            const lastNumInArray = acc.slice(-1)[0]
            // here is my hack if the small straight starts with 3 and the last die             is a 1
            if ( die - lastNumInArray === 2) acc = [die]
            if ( lastNumInArray === undefined || die - lastNumInArray === 1 )                     acc.push(die)
            return acc
        }, [] )
        if (straightFinder.length >= sizeOfStraight) return score
        return 0
    }

    console.log(score)
```

I got this to work, but it feels hacky. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

I am trying to make a basic Yahtzee game. Determining if a straight was rolled is where I got stuck. It basically worked, but if it was a small straight (4 in a row out of five dice) going from 3 - 6 AND the fifth die was a 1 my reduce would not work right. It always resolved to a 1 item array. I can see the problem in my logic, so I threw a little hack in there to make it work, but I feel like there must be a dozen better ways. Here is my code. Thanks for looking.

The dice are an array of 5 numbers 1-6 representing dice, the sizeOfStraight is just so I can reuse it for the large straight. The problem only came up with the small straight though, so you could just put a 4 in for that.

input dice = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
output (none, just returns because straightFinder.length = 1)

Comment: Please add examples of input input vs. expected output.

Comment: In addition of what @OriDrori says, this is pure JavaScript. Show a bit of effort and create a snippet so we can test it/fix it easily.

Comment: Unexpected is not exactly right. That was true when I started typing the question.. then I figured out what was happening. I am just looking for a better way. The unexpected output was that the second reduce was reducing it down to a 1 item array with the number 1 in it in the case I explained in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need `reduce` in that final operation. Just check the sorted dice at index 0 with index 3. If the latter has a value of 3 more than the first, the first 4 sorted dice represent a small straight. The same can be repeated at index 1 and index 4. There are no other positions possible for a small straight. A large straight can only start at index 0, so that only needs one check.

NB: extracting unique values can be done with the help of a temporary Set.

```js
const dice = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const score = straightScore(dice, 4);

function straightScore(dice, sizeOfStraight) {
    let score = 0;
    sizeOfStraight > 4 ? score = 40 : score = 30;
    dice.sort( (a, b) => a-b );
    // duplicates can be eliminated with a Set:
    const filteredDice = [...new Set(dice)];
    // determine straight: only two locations are of interest (at most)
    if (filteredDice[sizeOfStraight-1] - filteredDice[0] === sizeOfStraight-1) return score;
    if (filteredDice[sizeOfStraight] - filteredDice[1] === sizeOfStraight-1) return score;
    return 0;
}
 
console.log(score);
```

Comment: very clever. Thank you. Using Set is much cleaner. I also like the logic to determine the straight. That is a little more straight forward than my mess. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is a little overkill for Your needs, but may inspire You. Generally, I would create a "histogram" of rolled values and then look for the longest sequence of consecutive "hits" to find the longest straight.

### Approach 1:

Let's say, we rolled `dice = [6, 3, 1, 4, 3]`. The "histogram" would look like this:

```
0 - false (there's no dice roll 0)
1 - true
2 - false
3 - true
4 - true
5 - false
6 - true
7 - false (there's no dice roll 7)
```

Indexes 0 and 7 are useful as boundaries, which are guaranteed to be always false (which simpifies detecting straights starting at 1 or ending at 6). It can be created like this:

```
Array(8).fill(false).map((_, i) => dice.indexOf(i) >= 0)
-> [false, true, false, true, true, false, true, false]
```

Now we need to find length of the longest sequence of trues. Let's traverse through the histogram and detect changes from false to true (straight start) and back (straight end):

```js
function findStraights(dice) {

    const histogram = Array(8).fill(false).map((_, i) => dice.indexOf(i) >= 0)
    let straights = [];
    let start = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

        if (histogram[i - 1] === histogram[i])
            continue;

        if (histogram[i])
            start = i
        else
            straights.push({ start: start, length: i - start })
    }

    return straights
}

console.log(findStraights([]))
console.log(findStraights([5]))
console.log(findStraights([3, 2, 1]))
console.log(findStraights([4, 5, 6, 1]))
console.log(findStraights([6, 3, 1, 4, 3]))
```

Now we have array of all found straights and finding the longest one is trivial (sort(...)[0]).

### Approach 2:

Let's represent the histogram as a binary number (instead of the array shown above) and use a little bit-twiddling magic to determine longest sequence length:

```js
function findLongestStraight(dice) {

    let bits = dice.reduce((a, v) => a | (1 << v), 0)
    let longest = 0

    while (bits !== 0) {

        bits &= bits << 1
        longest++
    }

    return longest
}

console.log(findLongestStraight([]))
console.log(findLongestStraight([5]))
console.log(findLongestStraight([3, 2, 1]))
console.log(findLongestStraight([4, 5, 6, 1]))
console.log(findLongestStraight([6, 3, 1, 4, 3]))
```

The first line creates binary number `bits`, where every bit represents if given number was rolled on at least one die (bit 0 is always 0, bit 1 represents rolled 1 etc.) In our case `bits = 0b01011010 = 90`.

The `while` part uses a bit-twiddling trick, that [shortens every sequence of consecutive 1s by one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-longest-consecutive-1s-binary-representation/) on every iteration. All we do is count number of iterations needed to zero all sequeces.

Comment: I'm probably going to spend more time figuring out this answer than I did on my original formula... And I love it!!! This is definitely going to inspire me. Thanks for the feedback! Googling 'what is a histogram' now.

Comment: @JakeM Histogram is just that You create an array that tracks, which value was rolled how many times (in our case we just need to know if the value was rolled at all - that's why we are ok with true / false instead of number of "hits").